# The golden ratio in statistics of literature

Tags: statistics, applications, information-theory

Let a book, for example, or a poem... It consists in words and letters and symbols like : ;,!...
Let $W_b$=the number of words of the book.
Let $L_b$=the number of letters of the book.
The number $N_b$ is called : $\frac{L_b}{W_b}=N_b$.
Let now a dictionary of scrabble.
Let $W_d$=the number of words of the dictionary.
Let $L_d$=the number of the letters of the dictionary.
The number $N_d$ is called : $\frac{L_d}{W_d}=N_d$.
I calculated $\frac{N_d}{N_b}=j$, it is always near to $j=1.618$.
Is this result known in the literature ?
Are there analytical proofs of this result ?
The statistics are they the only way to prove this result ?
A talk is also a sequence of words and we can calculate the $j$ of a talk, if it is far from $1.618$, there is a problem, perhaps a sickness. Can we consider this method as a good test of normality and good health ? Can we prove it ?

Comment: I've never seen a Benford type law at work in this sense, but perhaps there is something subtle. Perhaps this is a corollary of Zipf's Law.

Comment: I apologize for closing this - I saw a flag and acted in haste. Let's let it run its course.

Comment: What is "near"? Are you counting $1.8$ as near? $1.65$? $1.618034$?

Comment: As long as the text is, as near to 1.618 the medium is... When we have one or two phrases, we will find 1.8 or 1.9, but continuing the counting, this medium will converge on 1.618 ! For scientific books, mathematics for instance, the reference-dictionary will be different, but the ratio-medium will always be near to the golden ratio !

Comment: As written in the answer, if anything like that is true, what you are saying is that there is a characteristic average word length of the texts supported by a particular type of dictionary.  That's plausible and not surprising.  It is also reasonable that a dictionary of X is more compressed (higher word length) than texts of X, which can be more conversational.  It is very unlikely, and if you think about it, contradictory to the preceding statements, that the text-to-dictionary compression factor would be a universal constant.

Comment: There is a (golden-ratio) tag that should probably be added.

Answer (score 2):

**If** those observations are correct, they are the same as saying that average word length ($N_t$) does not vary so much between different texts of type $t$.

The 4-digit accuracy 1.618... is meaningless, but it is possible that $t=$ dictionaries is a category with higher average word length than $t=$ novels, which have higher average word length than $t=$ children's books, and lower wordlength than $t=$ organic chemistry handbooks.